# using module.exports in an unusual way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I want to use the mongodb connection in other modules also so I chose this approach. 
Is there any drawback or something that I should be aware of.
I am going to require this file in my app.js file.
or Is there any other elegant way of doing the same thing .

```
const uri = "mongodb://localhost";
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

db = null ;
client.connect().then(()=>{
    db = client.db("mydb");
    db.collection("users").createIndex({ mobno: 1 }, { sparse: true, unique: true });
}).catch((error)=>{
    db = error;
});
while(true){
    if (db!=null){
        module.exports = db;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is best way to handle global connection of Mongodb in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397608/what-is-best-way-to-handle-global-connection-of-mongodb-in-nodejs)

Comment: What is that busy loop for?

Comment: Lots of things wrong with this.  For starters, your `while(true)` loop blocks the event loop so `db` can never get a value so your loop never completes.  Did you actually run this?  It will just be an infinite loop.  Until we have top level `await` that works with module initialization (which is being worked on), you cannot directly export a value obtained asynchronously.  Instead, you can export a promise and the caller has to use the promise to get the db.  Or export a function that returns a promise.

Comment: That's because I don't want null when I am using connection in other module. When I required this module in app.js I will be sure that my connection is opened

Comment: I guess @jfriend00 is right by this I will block the event loop and db will never get it's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of things wrong with this. This concept won't work.

For starters, your `while(true)` loop blocks the event loop so `db` can never get a value so your loop never completes.

When the network operation in the connect completes, it will add an event to the event queue and the callback associated with it (and then the resolved promise) can only run when you return control back to the event loop so that event can get processed.

But, your `while(true)` loop blocks the event loop so no events can get processed.  Unless you're using `await` inside the loop (which allows other events to run), you can't use a wait loop like this in node.js.  It just creates an infinite loop.

Until we have top level `await` that works with module initialization (which is being worked on), you cannot directly export a value obtained asynchronously.

Instead, you can export a promise and the caller has to use the promise to get the db. Or export a function that returns a promise.

More info on problems with the busy-wait while loop in these other answers:

[Wait until flag=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125865/wait-until-flag-true/22125978#22125978)

[javascript - What is wrong with this while loop? never ending loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676709/javascript-what-is-wrong-with-this-while-loop-never-ending-loop/38676722#38676722)

[Why does a while loop block the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824460/why-does-a-while-loop-block-the-event-loop/34825352#34825352)

Comment: I understood that this will block the event loop and the call in then will never be executed by the event loop.Can you share any resources or code which uses async await.

Comment: is below code is  the right way

Comment: db = null ;
module.exports = client.connect().then(()=>{
    db = client.db("mydb");
    db.collection("users").createIndex({ mobno: 1 }, { sparse: true, unique: true });
    return db ;
}).catch((error)=>{
    db = error;
});

Comment: @NamitPiriya - `async/await` won't really help you here.  There is NO way to directly export an asynchronously retrieved value.  You have to export a promise that the caller can use to get the value or the caller has to register a callback.  The db finishes its connection some indeterminate time in the future long AFTER `module.exports` has been assigned and the module is done loading.  There is a future proposal for nodejs for top level `await` along with asynchronous module loading, but that is not something we have yet.